# Extract pdf page and insert into existing pdf

Tags: java, itext

I have below `iText` code, I want to copy one page from src pdf file to other pdf file(I have existing `PdfStamper`, here it is `mainPdfStamper`).

```
PdfReader srcReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream("source.pdf"));

File file = File.createTempFile("temporary", ".pdf");

PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(srcReader, new FileOutputStream(file));
PdfImportedPage importedPage = pdfStamper.getImportedPage(srcReader, 1);

// copying extracted page from src pdf to existing pdf
mainPdfStamper.getOverContent(1).addTemplate(importedPage, 10,10);
pdfStamper.close();
srcReader.close();
```

This is not working and I am not aware of how to achieve this. In short, I want to copy one page from source pdf to existing pdf. Please help.

**UPDATE**

Below code worked as per the answer from Bruno.

```
    PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(srcPdf.getAbsolutePath());
    PdfImportedPage page = pdfStamper.getImportedPage(reader2, 1);
    stamper.insertPage(1, reader2.getPageSize(1));
    pdfStamper.getUnderContent(1).addTemplate(page, 100, 100);
    // Close the stamper and the readers
    pdfStamper.close();
    reader2.close();
```

Comment: Why are you using a `PdfWriter` instance? That doesn't make any sense, does it?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, It does not make sense. I have updated my question and removed it.

Comment: In that case: why didn't you remove `Document` instance along with it? I'll write you an answer pointing at the documentation where I explain how to achieve your requirement. There's more than one way to do what you want, but you seem to want to use `PdfStamper`.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, you are correct, I do not need `Document` too, I have updated my question. Please point me for the solution.

Comment: You have now removed the reference to `file1`...

Comment: @Bruno, I have updated code now. Does it look correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the documentation, for instance [chapter 6 of iText in Action](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/3/3c9ca46-76da-4de2-8972-b82efbe0bf88/samplechapter6.pdf). If you go to section 6.3.4 ("Inserting pages into an existing document"), you'll find the [InsertPages](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=120) example.

You only need this code if `p` is the page number indicating where you want to insert the page, `main_file` is the path to your main file and `to_be_inserted` the path to the file that needs to be inserted (`dest` is the path to the resulting file):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(main_file);
PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(to_be_inserted);
// Create a stamper
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
// Create an imported page to be inserted
PdfImportedPage page = stamper.getImportedPage(reader2, 1);
stamper.insertPage(p, reader2.getPageSize(1));
stamper.getUnderContent(i).addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
// Close the stamper and the readers
stamper.close();
reader.close();
reader2.close();
```

This is only one way to combine pages from two files. You can also use `PdfCopy` for this purpose. The advantage of using `PdfCopy` is the fact that you'll preserve the interactive features of the interactive page. When using `PdfStamper`, you'll lose any interactive feature (e.g. all links) that were present in the inserted page.

Comment: I have removed `stamper.insertPage(page, reader2.getPageSize(1));` as it is not supported in my 5.5.7 version. This worked for me. `pdfStamper` is in `for loop` and I want to close it at the end of for loop once all operations completed. is this possible?

Comment: What are you talking about? The method `insertPage(final int pageNumber, final Rectangle mediabox)` is most certainly present in iText 5.5.7 as you can clearly see in the GitLab repository: http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.java In your UPDATE, you are overwriting an existing page in the existing PDF. That's not correct. As for your question about a `for loop`: there is no `for loop` in your question, so I don't understand what you're talking about.

Comment: Now I see, I adapted an existing code snippet and I used `page` in an ambiguous way. You copy/pasted that example without understanding what you were doing. Please read *and understand* code before you copy/paste it.

Comment: This answer worked for me for copying page so I am accepting this as answer. I will ask new question for `for-loop`, thanks Bruno.