# Best approach to use PdfStamper in for loop

Tags: java, itext

I have below `iText` code to read files and adding it into master PDF file, so it is basically adding PDF page in the existing PDF at absolute position. Absolute position and page number in the master PDF will be decided dynamically. Sometimes it could be on page 1 with `100,100(x,y)` or page 2 with `250,250(x,y)`. I am looping through the PDF objects where each object represent PDF file, then I will apply business logic to convert PDF object into PDF file and that is `srcPdf`. Now I need to add this `srcPdf` at absolute position in master PDF(which is `pdfStamper` here):

```
for(ListOfPdfObject pdfObj: ListOfPdfObjects) {
    // code to create srcPdf so there will be new srcPdf for each iteration. srcPdf is flattened pdf of acro form field pdf.
    PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(srcPdf.getAbsolutePath());
    PdfImportedPage page = pdfStamper.getImportedPage(reader2, 1);
    pdfStamper.insertPage(1, reader2.getPageSize(1));
    pdfStamper.getUnderContent(1).addTemplate(page, 100, 100);
    pdfStamper.close(); // problem is here
    reader2.close();
}
```

Here `pdfStamper` is created outside `for-loop` like below:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(tempPdf));
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream(destPdf));
```

The problem is if I close `pdfStamper` after `for-loop` it throws `RandomAccessSource not opened` exception. If I close inside for loop I will have to create again inside `for-loop`. Could you please point me at right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in my answer to [Extract pdf page and insert into existing pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582245/extract-pdf-page-and-insert-into-existing-pdf), using `PdfStamper` is only one way to meet your requirement. `PdfStamper` is probably your best choice if you need to manipulate *a single PDF document* and it's possible to add *a single page* from *another PDF* as my previous answer demonstrates.

However, you now indicate that you have to concatenate multiple PDF files. In that case, using `PdfStamper` isn't the best choice. You should consider switching to `PdfCopy`:

Suppose that you have the following files.

```
String[] paths = new String[]{
    "resources/to_be_inserted_1.pdf",
    "resources/to_be_inserted_2.pdf",
    "resources/to_be_inserted_3.pdf"
};
```

You need to insert the first page (and only the first page) of each of these documents at the start of an existing PDF with path `"resources/main_document.pdf"`, then you could do something like this:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
document.open();
PdfReader reader;
for (String path : paths) {
    reader = new PdfReader(path);
    copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, 1));
    reader.close();
}
reader = new PdfReader("resources/main_document.pdf");
copy.addDocument(reader);
reader.close();
document.close();
```

As you can see, the `addPage()` method adds a single page, whereas the `addDocument()` method adds all the pages of a document.

**Update**

It seems that you don't want to *insert* new pages, but that you want to *superimpose* pages: you want to add pages *on top of* or *under* existing content.

In that case, you indeed need `PdfStamper`, but you're making two crucial errors.

1. You close the `stamper` inside the loop. Once the `stamper` is closed, it is closed: you can't add any more content to it. You need to move `stamper.close()` outside the loop.
2. You close the `reader` inside the loop, but `stamper` hasn't *released* the `reader` yet. You should *free* the reader first.

This is shown in the [SuperImpose](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/SuperImpose) example:

```
public static final String SRC = "resources/pdfs/primes.pdf";
public static final String[] EXTRA =
    {"resources/pdfs/hello.pdf", "resources/pdfs/base_url.pdf", "resources/pdfs/state.pdf"};
public static final String DEST = "results/stamper/primes_superimpose.pdf";

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SRC);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(DEST));
PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getUnderContent(1);
PdfReader r;
PdfImportedPage page;
for (String path : EXTRA) {
    r = new PdfReader(path);
    page = stamper.getImportedPage(r, 1);
    canvas.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    stamper.getWriter().freeReader(r);
    r.close();
}
stamper.close();
```

In this case, I always add the imported pages to page 1 of the main document. If you want to add the imported pages to different pages, you need to create the `canvas` object inside the loop.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. As I have mentioned `pdfStamper.getUnderContent(page, 0, 0);` I do not want to add whole page but I want to add pdf page at absolute position in the existing pdf. `copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, 1));` seems like adding whole page. correct me?

Comment: From your previous question and comments, it looks as if you want to add the whole page. That's also what happens when you use `addTemplate()`, isn't it? There is no `getUnderContent()` method that takes 3 parameters.

Comment: `addTemplate(page, x, y)` has `x` and `y` co-ordinates. I can not use `PdfCopy` if I have to place page at absolute position in other pdf, correct?

Comment: That's correct, but you should rephrase your question. Right now, there's an error in your code (you don't use `addTemplate()`) and you are *superimposing* pages instead of *inserting* pages. Don't ask people *how to insert a page* if you mean to say *how do I superimpose a page*. Your question is too confusing for anyone to answer. Please correct your question.

Comment: I agree with you, I have updated my question, does it look correct?

Comment: Not entirely... Do you understand the code you are writing?

Comment: I can't answer your question because I don't know what's inside the `for (...)`. You're also not telling us to on which page you want to superimpose an existing PDF. Is it on page 1? On all pages? You really need to improve your question.

Comment: I have detailed my question. Sorry for not explaining it initially. Does it understandable now?

Comment: I have updated my answer indicating the two errors you have in your code. I'll also update your question because you're still using a method that doesn't exist.

Comment: I was just missing `stamper.getWriter().freeReader(r);` Thanks for your help and sorry for not being clear on question.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie What about, if we need multipage pdf to be superimposed on a multipage pdf?