# iTextPDF: Superimpose static template to all pages of a PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a PDF with 12 pages of content. I have another PDF (with only 1 page) which is the graphic template.

Both PDF (content and template) are **A4 size, horizontally oriented**.

For each page of the PDF of contents, I need to apply the same template, as background

This is the code I made so far (my code [started from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582996/best-approach-to-use-pdfstamper-in-for-loop)), but I'm unable to retrieve the template page and apply it to each page.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // PDF with contents (12 pages)
    File pdfContent = new File("content.pdf");

    // PDF with template (1 page only)
    File pdfTemplate = new File("template.pdf");

    // Where to save the output file
    File output = new File("pdf_output.pdf");
    if (output.exists()) {
        output.delete();
    }

    // Opening reader on content PDF and creating stamper
    PdfReader contentReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(pdfContent));
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(contentReader, new FileOutputStream(output));

    // Looping through pages
    for (int i = 1; i <= contentReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        // Retrieve content page where to apply template
        PdfContentByte contentPage = stamper.getUnderContent(i);

        // Opening template pdf
        PdfReader templateReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(pdfTemplate));

        // Retrieve first page of template pdf (will be applied to content)
        PdfImportedPage templatePage = stamper.getImportedPage(templateReader, 1);

        // Apply template to PDF content
        contentPage.addTemplate(templatePage, 0, 0);

        // Closing reader
        templateReader.close();
    }

    stamper.getWriter().freeReader(contentReader);
    contentReader.close();

    // FIXME calling it throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already closed
    // stamper.close();
}
```

This code works, ends w/o any error, but the resulting PDF is corrupted and cannot be displayed.

Is PdfStamper the proper way to obtain the result I'm looking for?

How can I proper use the library in order to obtain the result?

---

**EDIT base on @mkl reply**

```
// Opening reader on content PDF and creating stamper
PdfReader contentReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(pdfContent));
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(contentReader, new FileOutputStream(output));

// Opening template pdf
PdfReader templateReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(pdfTemplate));
PdfImportedPage templatePage = stamper.getImportedPage(templateReader, 1);
templateReader.close();

// Looping through pages
for (int i = 1; i <= contentReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    // Retrieve content page where to apply template
    PdfContentByte contentPage = stamper.getUnderContent(i);

    // Apply template to PDF content
    contentPage.addTemplate(templatePage, 0, 0);
}

stamper.close();
contentReader.close();
```

In this edit I read once the template PDF e using `stamper.close()` at the end.
When calling `stamper.close()` I'm getting this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already closed
    at com.itextpdf.text.io.ArrayRandomAccessSource.get(ArrayRandomAccessSource.java:64)
    at com.itextpdf.text.io.IndependentRandomAccessSource.get(IndependentRandomAccessSource.java:77)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.read(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:225)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.readFully(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:247)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.readFully(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:241)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.getStreamBytesRaw(PdfReader.java:2665)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.getStreamBytes(PdfReader.java:2631)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.getPageContent(PdfReader.java:2385)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReaderInstance.getFormXObject(PdfReaderInstance.java:125)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage.getFormXObject(PdfImportedPage.java:136)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReaderInstance.writeAllPages(PdfReaderInstance.java:172)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addSharedObjectsToBody(PdfWriter.java:1368)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.close(PdfStamperImp.java:280)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper.close(PdfStamper.java:230)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do

```
stamper.getWriter().freeReader(contentReader);
contentReader.close();
```

This closes the reader the stamper is based upon and information from which the stamper needs at closing time.

But do

```
stamper.close();
```

During this the stamper finalizes the PDF document, adding object cross reference information to it.

Thereafter you can and should close the reader

```
contentReader.close();
```

That being said you should import the template page only once and then reuse the `PdfImportedPage templatePage`.

---

After the edit of the question:

Please also close the template pdf reader not before closing the stamper. I.e. move the line

```
templateReader.close();
```

after

```
stamper.close();
```

Comment: I edited the code using your suggestion (please see the updated part on the main question). I'm getting an exception while calling `close()` method on stamper

Comment: Please first move the reader `close` calls after the stamper `close` call. As soon as you have the code working in that constellation, you can test whether you can close the template reader earlier (for less resource usage) by moving that template `close` call up line by line, probably in combination with a `freeReader` call. As this is about a single reader only, not numerous ones, this attempt at optimization is purely optional.

Answer (score 1):

Basing on @mkl reply, here is the working result

```
// Opening reader on content PDF and creating stamper
PdfReader contentReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(pdfContent));
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(contentReader, new FileOutputStream(output));

// Opening template pdf
PdfReader templateReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(pdfTemplate));
PdfImportedPage templatePage = stamper.getImportedPage(templateReader, 1);

// Looping through pages
for (int i = 1; i <= contentReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    // Retrieve content page where to apply template
    PdfContentByte contentPage = stamper.getUnderContent(i);

    // Apply template to PDF content
    contentPage.addTemplate(templatePage, -40, -40);
}

stamper.close();

templateReader.close();

contentReader.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing mate. Was looking for an example to overlay one template on top of another PDF without losing ineractions (hyperlinks), this helped me a lot!